# document.getElementById().value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build basic Javascript calculator.

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="calculator">




<div id="calcname">
        <h3 id="calc">
            Basic Calculator
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="display">
        <input type="text" maxlength="40" size="30" name="Display" id="display" value="" /> 
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button id="seven" value="7" name="button" onclick="dplay();">
        7   
        </button>
        <button id="eight" value="8" name="button">
            8
        </button>
        <button id="nine" value="9" name="button">
            9
        </button><br />
        <button id="four" value="4" name="button">
            4
        </button>
        <button id="five" value="5" name="button">
            5
        </button>
        <button id="six" value="6" name="button">
            6
        </button><br />
        <button id="one" value="1" name="button">
            1
        </button>
        <button id="two" value="2" name="button">
            2
        </button>
        <button id="three" value="3" name="button">
            3
        </button><br />
        <button id="zero" value="0" name="button">
            0
        </button>
        <button id="dot" value="." name="button">
            .
        </button>
        <button id="/" value="/" name="button">
            /
        </button><br />
        <button id="*" value="*" name="button">
            *
        </button>
        <button id="-" value="-" name="button">
            -
        </button>
        <button id="+" value="+" name="button">
            +
        </button><br />
        <button id="C" value="C" name="button">
            C
        </button>
        <button id="AC" value="AC" name="button">
            AC
        </button>
        <button id="=" value="=" name="button">
            =
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

my javascript code:

```
function dplay(){ 
   var val=document.getElementsByTagName('button').value; 
   current+=val; 
   document.getElementByID("display").value=val; 
}
```

Why is that last line of code does not display value in textbox, which has `id="display`"?

I have tried this function for only one button. When button is pressed, this code should execute. But, when I tried it does not display.

I tried `innerHTML` property which I don't want, but even then it display undefined. I do not understand what is incorrect in above code. Please help.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('button')` is an `HTMLCollection`. It doesn’t have a `value` property.

Comment: i also tried document.getElementsByName('button').value should it work?

Comment: Why don’t you simply read the docs to those functions and look into the console for errors?

Comment: use `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('button')`

Comment: You'll get more effort if you put more effort out. Recreate your code on jsFiddle.net, CodePen.io, and/or use the snippet feature located on the toolbar (icon looks like a page with brackets in it).

Comment: var current="0";

function dplay(){
 var len=document.getElementById("buttons").children.length;
 for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
var val=document.getElementsByName('button')[i].value;
current+=val;
 document.getElementsByName("Display").value=val;
 }
} i tried looking at the error but it does not display and has no error... i dont understand.